# how to upload three json files in oneshot with spring integration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-sftp

I want to upload three json file from my local directory to a remote SFTP location in one shot. I cannot afford to upload them one by one. What inbound adaptor, channel  and sftpoutbound gateway configuration should I use ? I know there is something call mput in outbound gateway. But I have never used the mput code wise.

Answer (score 0):

See docs for MPUT command: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#using-the-mput-command

> The message payload must be a java.io.File (or String) that represents a local directory.

So, a request message for MPUT command must have a payload as a local dir with files you'd like to transfer. Therefore it might not be ideal for you to deal with a file inbound channel adapter.

You can aggregate polled files into a single directory before sending a message with it into that SFTP outbound gateway.

Comment: How to i deleted those json files after the sftp outbount gateway is done sending the file ? May be like this sudo code `serviceactivator 1 {   sendmultipleFiles(directory); clean(directory);   }`. Here sendmultipleFiles is a second serviceactivator with a gateway.

Comment: I would say this deserve its own StackOverlfow question since it won't contradict with rules applied here for content consistency.

Comment: Mput works with your suggestions , thanks