# How to use SFTP Spring Integration mput with SftpOutboundGateway when File object is directory?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-sftp

```xml
    <int-sftp:outbound-gateway session-factory="sftpSessionFactory"
                               use-temporary-file-name="false"
                               request-channel="tmpDirToUploadOutputChannel"
                               command="mput"
                               expression="payload"
                               remote-directory="/out"
                               reply-channel="sftpUploadFilesResultChannel">
    </int-sftp:outbound-gateway>`
```

when I send Message from service activator - File is directory with files

```kotlin
        val message = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(tmpOutFile)
//            .setHeader("file_name", tmpOutFileName)
            .build()
```

outbound-gateway use last file name and on server I can see only one file on server

How to use it correct and use all file names?

my message from service activator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeD8k.png)

Comment: Probably something else is going on in your application or environment. See this question and its comments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74271495/how-to-upload-three-json-files-in-oneshot-with-spring-integration. You can enable `trace` logging level for the `org.apache.sshd.sftp.client` to observe an interaction with SFTP.

Comment: @ArtemBilan message = 

{GenericMessage@12219} "GenericMessage [payload=tmp\out, headers={id=e26daa1a-d6e4-8996-a594-7299bd50bb39, timestamp=1696963620066}]"
 payload = {File@15566} "tmp\out"
  0 = {File@15579} "tmp\out\import_ngcc-source-system-code-1_20231004175512_20231010_204700.csv"
  1 = {File@15580} "tmp\out\import_ngcc-source-system-code-1_20231004175512_20231010_204700.csv.md5"
 headers = {MessageHeaders@15567}  size = 2
  "id" -> {UUID@15574} "e26daa1a-d6e4-8996-a594-7299bd50bb39"
  "timestamp" -> {Long@15576} 1696963620066

Comment: I'm not sure what you show there. Please, consider to add much more info into your question after edit. Reading logs or code from the comments is not convenient.

Comment: OK, I also see that final file name for sftp outbound-gateway comes from my sftp inbound-channel-adapter :)

Comment: I think file name for sftp outbound-gateway is cached in header file_name (sftp inbound-channel-adapter sets it)

Answer (score 2):

Eureka!

inbound-channel-adapter --> service-activator return Message file is directory --> sftp outbound-gateway

sftp outbound-gateway caches file name from inbound-channel-adapter in header file_name

when I set "file_name", ""

```kotlin
        val message = MessageBuilder
            .withPayload(File(tmpOutDirPath))
            .setHeader("file_name", "")
            .build()
```

also removeHeader doesn't work in this case

Better solution is defined it in outbound-gateway:

```xml
remote-filename-generator-expression="payload.getName()"
```

Comment: You can use a `<header-filter>` before your service activator. Or you can override a `fileNameGenerator` to look only into a `File` payload instead of that header attempt.

Comment: thx @ArtemBilan

Comment: I decided to go ahead and remove that header when we PUT specific item from MPUT request: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/8761